# Security error in OSX Safari for local html file

Tags: html, macos, security, safari

Facing a peculiar problem with security while running a local html file in OSX Safari.

> [Error] Not allowed to load local resource: file://secure.myshopmatemac.com/servicejs/components/?source‌​=mm-1643&version=2.0‌​&isn=800 Global Code (Script Element 1:1:735)

I am sharing the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

It would be of great help if you could help me understand why the problem and possible way to solve the problem.

Comment: It'd be cool if you paste the text of those error messages into the post. It will be easier to find for future readers.

Comment: More importantly this is happening in a static html page